# Website that recognizes user's location/IP & changes lang. based on that

Tags: javascript, html, web, geolocation

The title is pretty clear.

My website consists of both English-written and Spanish-written versions.
You can go to the main site, which is in Spanish, by clicking http://www.chrishonn.com and to the translated version, which is in English, at http://en.chrishonn.com. At the index of each page, there is a link (at the bottom) that allows the user to pass from one site to the other.

However, I was wondering, how big sites like Google, Yahoo!, and other brands' websites recognize the user's geographical location/IP so that - depending on that - the site's language is adapted (*i.e. you are from China and you visit [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), you'll be redirected to [www.google.cn](http://www.google.cn)*).

---

I have stated on every single page of my website the language:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
```

That example is of course from one of the http://en.chrishonn.com sites, which are in English.

I hope someone can give me a hand.
Thank you (if I missed something, please let me know).

Comment: If you choose to offer different languages based on geo-location, please consider offering an option to override the geo-location's best guess. It seems common for people in multilingual countries -Holland and Switzerland to name only two- for people to prefer another language than their country's official language.

Comment: In any case, there is a link to change back and forth between English and Spanish.

Comment: Or people who are visiting your site from a different country on holiday and want to read it in their native language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for Google, your location is determined from your IP address. A request to google.com from outside the US returns an `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` which redirects you to your country specific domain.

[As also discussed on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026755), doing these kinds of redirects can make SEO tricky and complicated. I suggest reading [Matt Cutt](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/about-me/)'s article (a Google software engineer) on how Google handles the 302 Redirect: [SEO advice: discussing 302 redirects](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-discussing-302-redirects/).

Different search engines handle the 302 redirect in a different way. With 302 redirects, you may risk having your original domain ignored by search engines.

---

If you want to determine your users' location from their IP address, there are many off-the-shelf services which basically map most of the IP ranges to countries. You may want to check:

- [MaxMind GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country)
- [IP2Location.com](http://www.ip2location.com/)

---

Another popular technique is to parse the Accept-Language HTTP header, which contains information about the user's language preferences. Mainstream browsers allow these language preferences to be modified by the user. You may read more about this technique from:

- [Parse Accept-Language to detect a user's language](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header)
- [W3C - Accept-Language used for locale setting](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales)

---

Comment: i think you are just copy&pasting answers from other questions on SO (maybe even your own?!).

Comment: Well done for noticing :) Yes, I copied a part from an answer I gave to another question on a similar topic.

Comment: I edited the post with the reference. Just in case someone else senses the deja-vu :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am downloading GeoLite Country and I'll have to figure out how to enable it ;).

Will update you ASAP.
Thank you again.

Comment: Well, this aged well.

Answer (score 13):

Rather than detecting the location of IP address (often unreliable due to NAT and proxying) you could check the default language the browser is set to.
There are JQuery plugins to support this, such as http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html, or use server-side code to read the HTTP request header "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" to determine if you want to show the ES or EN site.

Comment: +1 for Accept-Language, which is a **much** more suitable way to choose a language than geolocation (even if geolocation were 100% accurate). However, it should only be done on the server side. Accept-Language is not available on the client side; instead you only get `navigator.[user]Language`. However this setting is to do with the install language which, unlike the Accept-Language, is not easily user-configurable. Consequently it — and this plugin which uses it – should never be used.

Comment: I would have done this, indeed: For its simplicity and it'd have taken less time. However, many people (count me in) use another language in our browser(s)/OS(s) than the language we actually speak, or the country's official language.

Comment: @crozer: shouldn't you be most interested in what language the user requests to browse data in instead of their location?  I would think that the `Accept` header is the most indicative of the user's wishes.

Comment: @bobince: I'd go with server-side too, I mentioned the JQuery plugin because the question didn't reference any server-side technology, only "html" and "javascript".

Comment: Instead, why don't you read my last comment below :)
I don't wanna sound rude, but since I already wrote this code, could you please try it? If it does not work, I will do what you say here.

I would really appreciate this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

some website use IP address-based geo location, some us Accept language header (can be set in the browser). Anyway, from the usability point of view - always allow people to change the language and never display different content on the same IP (google and other search engines doesn't like it and it would be bad from SEO point of view).

Answer (score 1):

These sites often use tools that are generically called "geolocation software".

One of the most popular packages is the free [GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) database offered by MaxMind.  This will integrate into your application and provide IP-to-country lookups.  With Apache, you will have some environment variables set called GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE and GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME.

All your application has to do after that is decide where your user should be or what settings they should have by default based on the country, and redirect or output appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am downloading GeoLite Country right now. I will also check how to enable it, as I am pretty new to these sort of databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a GET request to this URL: https://api.teletext.io/api/v1/geo-ip and it will respond with some country information in JSON format. See https://teletext.io/help/geo-location-service for usage.

If you want to implement it yourself: I've set this up by using AWS Cloudfront, Cloudfront adds a header (Cloudfront-Viewer-Country) to your request before it forwards it to the origin server that you can use. Make sure to whitelist the header in your Cloudfront distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I have created cloud distribution and whitelisted the CloudFront-Viewer-Country header.
But when I accessed the object using this distribution I did not see it in the request header.

Comment: Warning : it's not a response for the issue