# How to automatically change the website language based on the user location

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, geolocation, multilingual

I am building a Multilanguage WordPress site using the Polylang plugin for the translation, I wanted to make the website change language based on the user location, so if for example, the user is in Egypt. He lives in Cairo I want the website to open in English language but if he tried opening it from Giza then the website should open in Arabic.

I tried using HTML5 geolocation and some JavaScript to check the latitude and the longitude of the user but it didn't work.

Do you have any ideas on how to make this happen either by a free plugin or a JavaScript code?

Comment: The solution here might help https://wpml.org/forums/topic/country-based-redirect/

Comment: I think it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039016/website-that-recognizes-users-location-ip-changes-lang-based-on-that